# Is this construction of the tensor product of Hilbert spaces valid?

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

This construction is found in Methods of modern mathematical physics vol. 1. [See page 49](https://books.google.dk/books?redir_esc=y&id=bvuRuwuFBWwC&q=Tensor%20product#v=snippet&q=Tensor%20product&f=false)

[image]

However it seems like this construction is flawed, if $(\cdot,\cdot)$ indeed is an inner product on $\mathcal{E}$ (for which he constructs $H_1\otimes H_2$ as its completion). For any $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\phi\in H_1,\psi\in H_2$
$$
a\phi\otimes \psi(x,y)= (x, \overline{a}\phi_1)(y,\phi_2) = (\bar{a}\phi_1)\otimes \phi_2(x,y).
$$
for any $(x,y)\in H_1\times H_2$.
That is, $a(\phi\otimes \psi) = (\bar{a}\phi)\otimes \psi$.

But if $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a inner product it is conugate linear in the second argument. Thus
$$
a\langle \eta\otimes \mu , \phi \otimes \psi\rangle =\langle \eta\otimes \mu , \overline{a}(\phi \otimes \psi)\rangle=\langle \eta\otimes \mu , (a\phi) \otimes \psi)\rangle = ( \eta, a\phi)(\mu,\psi) = \overline{a}( \eta, \phi)(\mu,\psi)=\overline{a}\langle \eta\otimes \mu , \phi \otimes \psi\rangle 
$$
for any $\eta,\phi\in H_1$ and $\mu,\psi\in H_2$.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: It is common in physics to define inner products to be conjugate linear in the *first* argument rather than the second.  You should double check which convention is used in this book.

Comment: Note that, in the notation of this book, $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes an inner product, but $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ does **not**.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks mate, I totally missed that. I guess it all works out alright then if i define $\phi_1\otimes\phi_2(\psi_1,\psi_2)=(\phi_1,\psi_1)_{H_1}(\phi_2,\psi_2)_{H_2}$ in terms of regular inner products. But does this also entail that i should define the inner product on $\mathcal{E}$ by $(\phi\otimes \psi,\eta\otimes\mu)=\overline{(\phi,\eta)(\psi,\mu)}= (\eta,\phi)(\mu,\psi)$, if i want to use normal inner products? Or do the rest of the construction carry out exactly as he states when using normal inner products?

Comment: I don't see a mistake in your calculation.  So, if you use "normal" inner products, something needs to get switched.

Comment: Well upon further inspection, it seem like I only need to define the simple tensor as $\phi\otimes \psi(x,y)= (\phi,x)_{H_1}(\psi,y)_{H_2}$ such that is also becomes a conjugate bilinear map (if I assume that $(\cdot,\cdot)_{H_1}$ is a normal inner product). Furthermore I don't  think i should change anything in the definition of the inner product on $\mathcal{E}$ because if i define $(\phi\otimes \psi,\eta\otimes\mu):= (\eta,\phi)_{H_1}(\mu,\psi)_{H_2}$ in terms of normal products on the RHS, then we get conjugate linearity in the first argument again, so we must still define

Comment: $(\phi\otimes \psi,\eta\otimes\mu):= (\phi,\eta)_{H_1}(\psi,\mu)_{H_2}$ even with normal inner products on the RHS. Do you agree? Btw please post your comment as an answer, and i will award you the points.

Comment: Wasn't planning on posting an answer.  You could post one on your own question.  Otherwise, I'll probably make an answer summing up what I said in the comments tomorrow, when I get the chance